# Command "npm install" exited with 1 (Error deploy in vercel)

Tags: vercel

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/classNameNamenames/-/classNameNamenames-2.5.1.tgz - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'classNameNamenames@https://registry.npmjs.org/classNameNamenames/-/classNameNamenames-2.5.1.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 This package name is not valid, because 
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /vercel/.npm/_logs/2024-02-23T14_23_36_789Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

I deploy 3D website on vercel and I am getting this error, although the local have no error. I have check my node version 20 and setting vercel node version 20 but still error.

Comment: `classNameNamenames` is indeed not an actual package. Maybe you meant... [`classnames`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)?

Comment: i just copy error vercel report , I really  don't know why it is classNameNamenames like this

Comment: npm ERR! 404  'classNameNamenames@https://registry.npmjs.org/classNameNamenames/-/classNameNamenames-2.5.1.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 This package name is not valid, because 
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /vercel/.npm/_logs/2024-02-23T14_32_25_968Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1